# Prove that $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{B}$ is invariant with respect to boost

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I tried to prove, that dot product of three vectors of electric and magnetic fields is invariant with respect to boost in any direction. Assuming $c=1$, I used Lorenz transformation
$$E_\parallel '=E_\parallel\\
B_\parallel '=B_\parallel\\
E_\bot'=\gamma(E_\bot+v\times B)\\
B_\bot'=\gamma(B_\bot-v\times E)$$
where $\parallel $ denotes components of field parallel to the velocity $\vec{v}$. Due to that $\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$ can be written as $\vec{v}\times\vec{B_\bot}$. Then I transformed the dot product

$$E'\cdot B'=(E_\bot'+E_\parallel)\cdot(B_\bot'+B_\parallel)=\\
=\gamma^2(E_\bot\cdot B_\bot-E_\bot\cdot(v\times E_\bot)+B_\bot\cdot(v\times B_\bot)-(v\times E_\bot)\cdot(v\times B_\bot))+\\
\gamma(E_\bot\cdot B_\parallel+B_\bot\cdot E_\parallel+B_\parallel\cdot(v\times B_\bot)+E_\parallel\cdot(v\times E_\bot))+E_\parallel\cdot B_\parallel$$

Knowing that
$$E_\bot\cdot(v\times E_\bot)=0\\
E_\parallel\cdot(v\times E_\bot)=0$$
and
$$(v\times E_\bot)\cdot(v\times B_\bot)=v^2E_\bot\cdot B_\bot$$
we can get transform the expression

$$E'\cdot B'=E_\bot\cdot B_\bot+\gamma(E_\bot\cdot B_\parallel+B_\bot\cdot E_\parallel)+E_\parallel\cdot B_\parallel$$

Now the only thing that's bugging me is the $\gamma$ in the middle term. Without it, the right side would clearly be equal to the $E\cdot B$. I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Comment: In fact it's invariant with respect to any Lorentz transformation, as it's proprortional to ${}^\ast F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any dot product between a parallel and perpendicular component is zero (even if they don't belong to the same field) so you just have

$$E'\cdot B'=E_\bot\cdot B_\bot+E_\parallel\cdot B_\parallel=E\cdot B.$$